# How to Change Price Set Field Type without deleting and re-adding

Tags: civievent, price-sets

I have some price set fields created as Radio currently, but they need to be Checkbox type. Is there any way to safely change (even in backend) without having to recreate the entire field (there are a lot of choices)

CiviCRM 4.6.x Drupal 7.x

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first answer is: yes you can do this in the backend! I just confirmed it: in the `civicrm_price_field` table find your `Price Field ID` (row) and then change the `html_type` from: `Radio` to: `CheckBox` I just did this on a dev site and my price/field?action=preview looks just fine - no errors/notices.

My responsible answer is: first make an extra backup - next make a clone of your project and make the edit to the `html_type` - check your contribution page(s) where you offer this `price_set` - run any report you would normally run to check to see that everything still adds up [IF you've already had users selecting these price_set fields so you have data in them already].

Comment: It is a form that has no data entered into it yet. I received the form from a client in advance, and made a bunch of fields using the wrong field type (changed later). Was hoping to not have to redo all the work. Thank you.

Comment: Then what I wrote above should work for you! Should take just a few min... if you have phpMyAdmin - it's an easy GUI edit. Let me know if you need some help with the MySQL command (if you need to go that route).

Comment: It appears to have worked. Thank you. I used PHPMyAdmin which has the quick edit feature.

Comment: Excellent! Best.

Comment: Want to take a stab at my next Q? http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12030/how-to-clone-a-price-set-field-and-its-options :)

Comment: :-)! I've got to finish some code work - will have a look later though

Comment: Hi @KarinG-SemperIT, I have to change field type of price set which has data to it? should I try it out on dev?

Comment: Yes try your specific type edit on dev first and look at your data generating some reports etc. to ensure all is well.