# How to Clone a Price Set Field and Its Options

Tags: civievent, price-sets

Currently one can Clone an entire Price Set, however it is not possible AFAIK to clone Price Fields with their Price Options.

Does anyone have a clever way to do this, front end or backend?

My situation: I am creating a large amount of fields, but many are just copies. Such as Person 1 Data, Person 2 Data, Person 3 Data. I need to clone everything EXCEPT the Price Field Title.

Thanks! (and take pity on my wrists and mouse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry - your best bet is a big pot of coffee and just getting it done via the GUI! That's because there are quite a few places in the database that are touched when storing price options. Even with phpMyAdmin access (like you have) it's going to be a lot of copying of rows - then updating IDs - carefully linking them properly to the other tables involved in Pricesets. Something is likely going to be out of place. Best to use the GUI.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this was the answer, but I also figured it was worth avoiding carpal tunnel syndrome by asking the question. Also, this sounds like it would be a worthy extension to be made (or perhaps core functionality).

Comment: Yes - that would indeed be useful - I think a lot of us have been there - done that!